# What's a proper method for analyzing an intervention in a seasonal time-series?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, intervention-analysis

My data has the following structure (I cannot post the real data):

[image]
The data contains 20 shapes (round, squared, triangle), 2 were chosen for simplicity.
The data is recorded for almost 2 years (aprox 600 rows), and it will
keep growing.

The data presents a seasonal pattern for freq=7 days (1 week).

Starting from week 30 were implemented multiple interventions in order to lower the number of damaged pieces. Let's say there are 3 interventions: inter1, inter2, and inter3.
They (interventions) are executed in a following way: inter1 is executed in week 30, inter2 is executed in week 31, inter3 is executed in 32, and cycle will start again with inter1.

The goal is to develop a model that measures the intervention, and to see if the error rate (damaged pieces / total pieces)  has decreased/increased. As it can be seen, the number damaged pieces depend on the number total pieces,  but it can depend on the number of round or squared shapes created in that day.

My approach so far:
Fitting SARIMAX (only total pieces as exogenous variable) on days before the intervention, then forecasting for the days (next 7 days) following the intervention (usually happens in weekends). The final step is to compare the true data against the forecast data. If the true data is outside the confidence intervals then the intervention is significant.

The model is intended to be used for future data.

My question is: What's the proper method/approach for measuring such interventions, and to see if they (interventions) are significant? How's the current approach, is it suited for this problem?